# not able to append to a file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
dirs=( * )
for f in "${dirs[@]}"
do
  while IFS= read -r line; do
     case "$line" in
       *disabled\>true* )
          sed -i '1i "$f"' list.txt;;
     esac
  done < "$f/config.xml"
done
```

Instead of sed, I tried echo and printf too but the the file list.txt is always empty. Why am I not able to append to file?

```
echo "$f" >> list.txt;;
printf '%s\n' "$f" >> list.txt;;
```

sample config.xml file under test folder:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
<disabled>true</disabled>
</project>
```

Goal: Print "test" into list.txt, if test/config.xml has `<disabled>true` in it.

Comment: Does running `bash -x yourscript` show that the append lines (of which the `printf` solution is most robust) are actually invoked?

Comment: bash -x shows sed statement invoked, but not echo. I even tried echo "am here". But it is not invoked :-(

Comment: Hmm. Flow control itself doesn't vary. Can you make your example in the question usable standalone (ie. have it create config.xml files itself, so someone can reproduce your problem without needing a bunch of content that isn't shown)?

Comment: Alternately, if you unconditionally `printf 'line=%q\n' "$line"` immediately within the `while read` before the `case`, and find the individual line where it *should* be triggering but isn't, then you can include only the assignment of the `line` variable and then the `case` statement in your question, and leave out the `for` loop and not need any input files as a necessary part of reproducing the issue.

Comment: Did you notice that you're trying to expand `"$f"` inside single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that your sed expresion is not working with empty files. I modified the code and it satisfies your goal:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

for f in */config.xml # process all config.xml files
do
  while IFS= read -r line; do
     case "$line" in
       *disabled\>true* )
          # obtain directory name of the file
          # and append it to list.txt
          dirname "$f" >> list.txt 
     esac
  done < "$f"
done
```

However, I'd rather use the following approach:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

for f in */config.xml 
do
  # -m1 - exit at first occurence for performance
  if grep -m1 'disabled>true' "$f" >/dev/null; then
      dirname "$f" >> list.txt
  fi
done
```

Or even simpler:

```
grep -l 'disabled>true' */config.xml | cut -d/ -f1 > list.txt
```

Comment: ++ for great optimizations, but please double-quote the `$f` instances; Also, `grep -q` is simpler than `grep -m1 >/dev/null`.
Finally, note that the OP's solution would have resulted in the directory names appearing in _reverse_ order in `list.txt`, though I'm not sure if that is really the intent.

Comment: I like your approach. Very simple and easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

To efficiently do what you *attempted* to do in your question use (requires GNU utilities):

```
grep -FZl 'disabled>true' */*.config.xml | xargs -0 dirname | tac > list.txt
```

This assumes that you want:

- only *directory* names recorded in `list.txt` (simply remove `| xargs -0 dirname` if you want the (relative) *file* paths).
- in *reverse* alphabetical order - if you want ascending order, simply omit the `| tac` part.

**Explanation:**

- Glob `*/*.config.xml` efficiently returns the (relative) file paths of `config.xml` files in any subdirectories of the current dir.
- `grep -FZl 'disabled>true'` searches for literal (`-F`) `disabled>true` in the input files and, only if and once the *first* match is found, stops searching and prints the input file path (`-l`), with multiple paths separated with `NUL` chars. (`-Z`).
- `xargs -0 dirname` passes the input, split into arguments by `NUL` (`0`), to `dirname`, which results in the *directory names* of those directories whose `config.xml` files contained the string of interest.
- `tac` reverses the lines
- `> list.txt` writes the overall result to file `list.txt`

---

As for the **problems with your attempt**:

- `dirs=( * )` captures *any type* of filesystem item in the current dir (if you know that the current dir only contains *directories*, that may not be a problem);
  `dirs=( */ )` would restrict matching to directories only (but note that the matches would include the trailing `/`).
- The fundamental problem with `sed -i '1i ...' list.txt`, as [user2021201](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164061/user1164061) points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930796/45375), is that *nothing is ever added* to `list.txt` if it starts out as an *empty* (zero-byte) file: the script is simply never executed for an empty input file.

  - There is no simple, single-command `sed` solution for this problem; for *appending* to a file incrementally, `>>` is the right choice.
- Additionally, `sed -i '1i "$f"' list.txt`, as [Rany Albeg Wein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5649859/rany-albeg-wein) points out in a comment on the question, tries to expand `$f` in inside a *single-quoted* string, which won't work - instead, *literal* `"$f"` will be written to the file (assuming the file is nonempty).
  Also, by using `1i` (insert before the 1st line), each new entry will be added as the *first* line, effectively resulting in `list.txt` containing the matching dirs. in *reverse* order.
- By not exiting the `while` loop once a match is found, you not only needlessly process the remaining lines in the file, but you also risk adding the directory at hand *multiple* times to `list.txt` in the event that the search string is found on more than 1 line.
- As [user2021201](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164061/user1164061) points out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930796/45375), your approach is inefficient, because (a) a multi-level glob such as `*/*.config.xml` can be used in lieu of a loop, and (b) because `grep` can be used to more efficiently search the contents of each file and exit once the first match is found (with `grep -m1` or  `grep -q` or `grep -l`, all with slightly different semantics).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and pointing out all the issues with my code.

Comment: using xargs and creating a new process for every line is not eficient. The advantage of `cut` is that it creates the process one single time and then pipes data through it.

Comment: `xargs` creates only _1_ process in this case (unless the list of file paths grows so large that it won't fit on a single command line). The advantage of `xargs -0 dirname` over your `cut` solution is that it works with multi-directory-component paths as well (not an issue in the OP's scenario, but it's good to have a more generic solution).

Comment: @user2021201: To verify that only a _single_ process is created, try `printf 'one\0two\0three' | xargs -0`.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I am just too used to use xargs with -n1, sorry for misunderstanding.